# SciTe for OS X Yosemite - error: cannot be used within an App Sandbox

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, sandbox, scite

I recently purchased Scite for my Macbook Pro, running OS X Yosemite intending to use it for Java/C++. When going to compile a test program in c++ I got the error message: "xcrun: error: cannot be used within an App Sandbox." I read on the Scintilla website something along the lines of sandbox preventing certain applications from accessing/opening files unless explicitly done so by the user. They stated that I can go to the Scite file menu, and select "Allow Access..." here I can add a path which I want to be allowed. I did a search in terminal for "whereis g++" and got the path "usr/bin/g++" so I added the "usr/bin" path to the allow access dialog box. After doing this I tried to compile and nothing was different. I tried adjusting the .cpp properties:

cc=g++ $(ccopts) -c $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).o

ccc=gcc $(ccopts) -c $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).o

to

cc=usr/bin/g++ $(ccopts) -c $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).o

ccc=usr/bin/gcc $(ccopts) -c $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).o

and then I get the error "/bin/bash: usr/bin/g++: No such file or directory" even though am able to see the file and directory in the allow access panel, and also was given the path in terminal. 
At this point I am completely lost and hope I didn't waste $50 as Scite is not free on Mac!

Does anyone know a solution?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is a support address for SciTE for OS X shown through the App Store http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE-Support.html .

The C/C++ compiler used to work in SciTE but this stopped when the compiler started to use xcrun. The assembler and linker also go through xcrun so it is not possible to install an independent copy of gcc (or clang) to work around this.